# Reference for equivalent definitions of the genus

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-curves, cv.complex-variables

Let $X$ be a (edit: nonsingular) projective complex algebraic curve.  The genus of $X$ can be defined as the dimension of the space of holomorphic $1$-forms on $X$, which in turn can be defined either analytically or algebraically in terms of Kahler differentials.  It can also be defined as the topological genus of $X$ considered as a surface, which in turn can be defined either topologically as the number of tori in a connected sum decomposition of $X$ or homologically in terms of the Betti numbers of $X$.  Does anyone know of a reasonably self-contained reference where some or all of these equivalences are proven?

(There is a [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152/how-do-you-see-the-genus-of-a-curve-just-looking-at-its-function-field) about computing the genus of a curve from its function field as well as a nice [post by Danny Calegari](http://lamington.wordpress.com/2009/09/23/how-to-see-the-genus/) explaining the relationship to the Newton polygon, but I am mostly interested in the algebraic-to-topological step of going from Kahler differentials to the number of tori in a connected sum decomposition.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $\mathrm{dim} H^0(X, \Omega^1_X) = \dim H^1(X, \mathbb{Q})$ see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_theory. For $\dim H^1(X, \mathbb{Q}) =$ number of tori use induction and the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

(And for $\mathrm{dim} H^0(X, \Omega^1_X) = \mathrm{dim} H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre_duality.)

Comment: All right, help me out here; which one of the things I said is the sheaf cohomology?

Comment: "the dimension of the space of holomorphic 1-forms on X" is $\mathrm{dim} H^0(X,\Omega^1_X)$. $\mathrm{dim} H^1(X,\mathbb{Q})$ is sheaf or singular cohomology.

Comment: Sure, but which one of the things I said is $\dim H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$?  

Comment: None, I added it just for reference.


Comment: @Qiaochu: There's a theorem called Serre Duality which tells you that for an Algebraic Curve (smooth, projective) you have $\dim H^1(X,O_X)=\dim H^0(X,\Omega^1_X)$, reference is Fulton's "Algebraic Curves" book, or Hartshorne, or Griffiths and Harris, or...any book on algebraic geometry, really.